# Is there a way to way to control which CNAME gets what content?

Tags: express, dns, cname

My ultimate goal is to have free plan cname content, and premium plan cname content.
For example if someone has a cname of `free.example.com` set to my website I'd like to show them a specific page, and if `premium.example.com` I want to show them another page. Finally, I'd like to know if there is a way to add new cnames to my list so that I can have them view a certain page?

Just to make this more understandable this, I want to do something like `https://www.gitbook.com/` do with their cnames, and cname serving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use the `Host` header from the user's request to identify which subdomain or cname they're visiting, and then showing them the desired content. If the subdomain such as *free* and *premium* are fixed, you could use Nginx server blocks or Apache virtual hosts to direct the user to specific application or application URI.

Likewise, you can get the `Host` header with [`req.hostname` in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname). Based on the host, you can route the user to the desired content. You can add as much subdomains or cnames you wish and let your application control the content for the user based on the host. If your DNS host has an API (such as [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com/)), you can add your subdomains programmatically, or you could do a wildcard subdomain to accept any subdomain.